# Mysql join multiple tables and column repeated

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I know how to join multiple tables, but I tried to show a value taken from 1 column in two different columns.

So:

table1.codseller = table2.id
and
table1.codbuyer = table2.id

Example:

```
TABLE1

id_ord    | order | codseller  | codbuyer| qty           | price
----------+-------+------------+---------+---------------+---------
09518709  | 4     | 001        | 002     | 8888          | 5
09518710  | 5     | 002        | 004     | 8888          | 6
09518712  | 6     | 001        | 006     | 8888          | 9
09518713  | 7     | 001        | 003     | 8888          | 4


TABLE2

    id        | location | 
    ----------+-------+--
    001       | USA      | 
    002       | CAN      | 
    003       | GER      | 
    004       | USA      | 
    005       | GER      | 
    006       | UKN      |  



RESULT:

id_ord    | order | codseller  | codbuyer| sel_loca     | buy_loc
----------+-------+------------+---------+---------------+---------
09518709  | 4     | 001        | 002     | USA          | CAN
09518710  | 5     | 002        | 004     | CAN          | USA
09518712  | 6     | 001        | 006     | USA          | UKN
09518713  | 7     | 001        | 003     | USA          | GER
```

Comment: This is exactly the situation where a `join` is needed...

Comment: yes i have already used join, the problem comes when I try to show location 2 times, in the result, once referring to seller location and the other referring to buyer locations.

Comment: Use join twice?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was put on hold. It may not be perfect, but it seems fairly understandable and already has a marked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subqueries as shown below.

```
SELECT 
  A.id_ord,
  A.id_ord,
  A.order,
  A.codseller,
  A.codbuyer,
 (SELECT location FROM TABLE2 B WHERE B.id=A.codseller LIMIT 1) sel_loca, -- this should work as just a single result will be returned
 (SELECT location FROM TABLE2 B WHERE B.id=A.codbuyer LIMIT 1) buy_loc
FROM TABLE1 A;
```

See the [**query run on SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2dc1a/5).

Comment: Working perfectly! Many thanks for your help.

Comment: The problem of using this and not JOIN, is the error:
Error with SQL statement: Subquery returns more than 1 row.
In some programs.

Comment: I just limited the number of row of data to be output by the subquery.

Comment: I would suggest using two joins on table2 instead of subqueries. I was going to add an alternative answer for that, but the question got closed. @kurtinho out of curiosity, what instances were you getting more than 1 row? If you are selecting from a lookup table using the PK you shouldn't have more than 1 result. cdaiga, if you don't mind I can just edit your answer and add my suggestion to it.

Comment: @gmiley yes, that have fix the error. Perfect!